# HTML5 - Source element attribute question

Tags: html

What are all the possible values for the source elements media attribute?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[The standard for HTML5](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/video.html#the-source-element) says:

> The media attribute gives the intended
>   media type of the media resource, to
>   help the user agent determine if this
>   media resource is useful to the user
>   before fetching it. Its value must be
>   a valid media query.

If you follow that, it will lead you to the [Media Queries](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css3-mediaqueries/) page.

The normative reference for media types is the [CSS2.1](http://www.w3.org/TR/2009/CR-CSS2-20090908/media.html) standard, which states:

```
all
  Suitable for all devices.
braille
  Intended for braille tactile feedback devices.
embossed
  Intended for paged braille printers.
handheld
  Intended for handheld devices (typically small screen, limited bandwidth).
print
  Intended for paged material and for documents viewed on screen in print preview mode. Please consult the section on paged media for information about formatting issues that are specific to paged media.
projection
  Intended for projected presentations, for example projectors. Please consult the section on paged media for information about formatting issues that are specific to paged media.
screen
  Intended primarily for color computer screens.
speech
  Intended for speech synthesizers. Note: CSS2 had a similar media type called 'aural' for this purpose. See the appendix on aural style sheets for details.
tty
  Intended for media using a fixed-pitch character grid (such as teletypes, terminals, or portable devices with limited display capabilities). Authors should not use pixel units with the "tty" media type.
tv
  Intended for television-type devices (low resolution, color, limited-scrollability screens, sound available).
```

Note that HTML4 has a different list of media types:

> ‘print’, ‘screen’, ‘aural’, ‘braille’, ‘handheld’, ‘print’, ‘projection’, ‘screen’, ‘tty’, ‘tv’.

Comment: but what are the allowed values in the Media Queries page?

Comment: are these all the predefined values?

Comment: did you find any more in the CSS specification that is linked?

Comment: there are no more in HTML5. HTML4 is different.

Comment: what do you mean there is no more in HTML5 can' I use the ones from past versions of HTML?

Comment: the list above is the _normative_ list of media types as referenced by the Media Query spec, which is referenced by the HTML5 spec, so right now this is all that you have for HTML5. This may change since HTML5 is not finalized AFAIK.

Answer (score 0):

Either `all` or a [media query](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css3-mediaqueries/). Providing an exhaustive list would be impractical (`device-width: 1px`, `device-width: 2px`, `device-width: 3px`, etc)

Comment: but what are the allowed values in the Media Queries page?

Comment: Click the link to see the spec. I'm not going to provide an exhaustive list as it would be infinitely long, and I'm not going to copy out the specification as that would be pointless.

Comment: I really can't make sense of the specs:(

Comment: The media queries spec is brimming over with simple examples.

Comment: But is there is a set list of predefined values like all?

Comment: No more then there is a set list of predefined values for the `style` attribute.

Comment: Well thats odd because there are values screen, tty aint that not part of a predefined list?

Comment: From http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css3-mediaqueries/#media0 : "A media query consists of a media type and zero or more expressions that check for the conditions of particular media features.". There is some attempt at listing the available media types after example 2 in the background section — http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css3-mediaqueries/#background — which suggests that media types are a fairly fuzzy concept and new ones can be defined by various different specifications (some of which may not exist yet). That only covers the first part of a media query though, the expressions are the important part

Answer (score 0):

According to the HTML5 specification, you can enter any valid "media query" into the `@media` attribute. This includes all of the regular values such as `screen`, `print` and so-on, but you can do more advanced stuff as described in the link below:

http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css3-mediaqueries/#media0

Examples:

```
<source media="screen and (device-aspect-ratio: 16/9)" src='video1_widescreen.ogv' type='video/ogg; codecs="theora, vorbis"'>
<source media="screen" src='video1.ogv' type='video/ogg; codecs="theora, vorbis"'>
<source media="not screen" src='video1_poster.jpg'>
```

Answer (score 0):

From the draft of the [HTML 5 spec](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/Overview.html):

> The media attribute gives the intended media type of the media resource, to help the user agent determine if this media resource is useful to the user before fetching it. Its value must be a valid media query.

And:

> A string is a valid media query if it matches the media_query_list production of the Media Queries specification.

The Media Queries (MQ) spec is [here](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css3-mediaqueries/).

Comment: but what are the allowed values in the Media Queries page?