# HTML5 media attribute question

Tags: css, html

I was reading another SO question [HTML5 - Source element attribute question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5687952/html5-source-element-attribute-question) and was wondering dosen't the media attribute have operators like (and) as well as values like (device-width) just not only devices? If so can some one point me to the docs that explain how to use the operators and values for the media attribute?

Comment: It's the same media query document that I pointed you to in the question that you reference.

Comment: @David Dorward, What are you talking about you didn't point me anywhere BoltClock did.

Comment: I checked his answer... it turns out the phrase "media query" was a link to the exact same page I linked to. Oh well, anyway you now know where to read about it, and that's what matters!

Comment: All four answers to that question link to the media queries spec! (And  BoltClock didn't participate in it at all.) (Although I assumed you had asked both questions, which was a mistake)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Multiple answers to that question refer to the `media` attribute having support for CSS3 media queries, which are exactly the stuff you're talking about. Read about them [here](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css3-mediaqueries).